# How to get a value from text using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

Currently I'm working on cv parser in java.I want to get date of birth details so I developed RegEx for the text

```
Date Of Birth xx-xx-xxxx
```

As

```
(?<=Date (of|Of) Birth)\\s*(.*)
```

And it works fine.

But I'm not getting value if the text is as "Date of Birth: xx-xx-xxx"

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: what is the regex to get date of birth if the text is as "Date Of Birth :xx-xx-xxxx " i'm not getting the value with colon(:). The above regex works if the text given as "Date Of Birth xx-xx-xxxx"(with out colon:)

Comment: Well, You have no colon in the regex!

Comment: Also, if you have an actual *Java question*, you can [edit] with some *Java code*. As-is, this is just regex.

Comment: @user999 please [edit] your question. People won't read the comments before they get interested.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
(date of birth)[^\d]*((?:\d{2}-){2}\d{4})
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/4e9eYx/1)

1. `(date of birth)` matches date of birth as case insensitive
2. `[^\d]*` this will allow to ignore anything but digits as it scans for
   the date format. It will let you have better control to cover more cases not just two.
3. `((?:\d{2}-){2}\d{4})` It matches the date format
4. Don't forget to use case insensitive option , in your code ( see the
   sample)

Sample Code:

```
final String regex = "(date of birth)[^\\d]*((?:\\d{2}-){2}\\d{4})";
final String string = "Date Of Birth 12-03-1995\n"
     + "Date of Birth: 02-01-2002";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("DOB Label: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("DOB Value: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```